# Ruby on Rails Gem or Bower for CSS and Javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, dependencies, bower

In Ruby on Rails, which is better for CSS and Javascript dependencies?

To install them as Gem or as Bower dependency? Such as **[jQuery](https://jquery.com/)** and or [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com)?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to install CSS frameworks like Bootstrap as a Gem. Here is my favorite Bootstrap installation guide: https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1

jQuery is already included in the default Rails setup.

Answer (score 0):

This is very much a personal preference. There are schools of thought that go both ways.

- I haven't looked in a long time, but oftentimes the gems are usually behind the current release of front-end libraries.
- UI portability is greater if you keep the frontend/backend logic completely separate. If you wanted to switch to another backend tomorrow, how long would it take?
- Using gems is faster, and you have a single tool (bundler) to handle the depedencies.

I have avoided providing my personal preference in favor of a neutral post.

Answer (score 0):

AS my opinion ....
rather than gem/bower, you should download files and integrate to project

like for bootstrap [download bootstrap files](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)

Comment: I don't think it's that manageable on a large project. Say you have hundreds of dependencies, going to each plugin's(CSS,JS) website, downloading it from there and trying to remember what you did and how you did it is very frustrating.

Comment: all gems also have these files ...and their self configuration code..so it will also increase total number of lines..      Cdn may be best solution if you don't  want  max code.

Comment: I think CDN is great to, especially when browers love to cache. I'd prefer that too, but depending on the plugin you'll need. Loading Bootstrap from CDN is great. But loading something that isn't that popular isn't. Thus we'll consider just keeping it to our own, as in here, Bower or Gem.